# LPTHW exercise 43 - Creating objects by returning constructors from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, constructor

[Exercise 43](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/python3/ex43.html) of Learn Python the Hard Way uses a dictionary whose values are constructors. The dictionary is defined within a class. 
I don't understand what happens when this class returns one of the dictionary values. Is a new object of a given class returned each time?

```
class Map(object):

    scenes = {
        'central_corridor': CentralCorridor(),
        'laser_weapon_armory': LaserWeaponArmory(),
        'the_bridge': TheBridge(),
        'escape_pod': EscapePod(),
        'death': Death(),
        'finished': Finished(),
    }

...
```

Here's the method which returns a value from the dictionary *scenes*

```
def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        val = Map.scenes.get(scene_name)
        return val
```

Does returning the dict values create a new object *each time* it is returned?
Are the objects from the dictionary created upfront when Python first sees the class definition?

The exercise is a game where the player can go between different scenes. So potentially the player can go into one scene multiple times. If the code creates a new object each time then there would be as many objects as the number of times the user enters the scene.

Answer (score 2):

The dictionary is created when the class `Map` is created, and all the class objects acting as dictionary values are instantiated once upon the dict creation.

> Is a new object of a given class returned each time?

Only one dict object is created on the class. No new ones are created when the dict is accessed via the class as in `Map.scenes`.

> Does returning the dict values create a new object each time it is
>   returned?

No. The initial class instances upon dict creation are always returned.